# Cloudflare and next.js static exports not working?

Tags: next.js, cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

It normally works but suddenly it stoped working and im not sure
why. If you can help thanks!

logs

```
2022-11-24T13:14:56.98176Z  Executing user command: next build && next export
2022-11-24T13:14:57.075259Z /opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:344
2022-11-24T13:14:57.075558Z                     ...pageKeys.app ?? [], 
2022-11-24T13:14:57.075709Z                                      ^
2022-11-24T13:14:57.075852Z 
2022-11-24T13:14:57.075978Z SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
2022-11-24T13:14:57.076087Z     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
2022-11-24T13:14:57.076193Z     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
2022-11-24T13:14:57.0763Z       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2022-11-24T13:14:57.076409Z     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2022-11-24T13:14:57.076516Z     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
2022-11-24T13:14:57.076621Z     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
2022-11-24T13:14:57.076736Z     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2022-11-24T13:14:57.076877Z     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js:10:37)
2022-11-24T13:14:57.077002Z     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2022-11-24T13:14:57.077111Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2022-11-24T13:14:57.082209Z Failed: build command exited with code: 1
2022-11-24T13:14:57.927713Z Failed: an internal error occurred
```

It exports the files and deploys to cloud flare

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting indicates that your Node version does not support the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing), which is part of Node as of version 14.
From reading the [Cloudflare docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/build-configuration/#language-support-and-tools) I understand that the default Node version is 12, which would match this suspicion.

The solution then would be to update your Cloudflare configuration to use a newer version (14+) of Node (see [docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/build-configuration/#language-support-and-tools)).